# What is the first parameter of a Writeable stream's close event handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

When a [`Writeable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) stream closes, the `close` event handler is executed with the argument `false`. The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_close) don't specify what that parameter represents like they do for the [`error`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_error) event. Does anybody know what `false` means?

```
let proc: ChildProcess = cp.spawn(somePath);
proc.stdin.on("close", () => { // kill the spawned process to execute this handler
    console.log(arguments); // [false]
}
```

Comment: Just guessing here but it seems you got the wrong docs page. Have a look [here](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_close_1). Have been referenced by Process.stdin which refers to being a net.Socket .

Comment: @getjackx `proc.stdin` is a stream of type `Writeable`, which is what my docs page links to, so I don't understand why you say that I have the wrong docs page. That being said, `net.Socket` is a `Duplex` stream, so maybe that parameter got unintentionally stuck in the `Writeable` `close` callback. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is [isException](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/7d77068c786d81fa43b6b6d80ac97e1bd53be4c8/lib/net.js#L596).

You can deduce this yourself by printing the stack trace inside of the `close` handler via `console.trace()`, which will get you:

```
Trace
    at Socket.require.spawn.stdin.on (/Users/user/Desktop/support/f.js:2:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:596:12)
```